# Auto-Incrementing (Unique) ID in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

i am trying to extend alfresco's document management by running a script. So far, i have managed to create a Custom Model with a Custom Type and Property as seen below:

[image]

the said Custom Type is under this Custom Model (never mind the Custom Aspect for now)

[image]

the custom type is working so far, i managed to apply it to a certain document as you can see below (Notice the Control Code Field)

[image]

now what i want to do is to add an auto incrementing function that will be set as the value of the *Control Code* Property (ie: [FILE0012])

i tried utilizing the scripts rule from alfresco but it seems like the commands are limited to that of alfresco's functionalities. not even *alert()* or *console.log* functions work. i thought that if i can make a script that could call an ajax to my php server, i can extract the document's property, and insert it to my database and get the rowid then attach it to a word "FILE" so it becomes the *Control Code* Property (ie: a document was inserted to my database at row 1996, then the Control code is [FILE1996], this is because i joined '[FILE' and 1996 and ']'

but like i said, what happened was, the javascript commands are limited to that of alfresco's needs.

i tried to make my research but i've only bumped on 2 outdated (and i mean outdated) threads dating back to 2006-2010. which does not help me quite well with Alfresco's current build structure.

i hope someone can help me with here. connecting to the database is not mandatory, but if i can make it do as such then it'll give me quite a rather amazing results.

Comment: I hope I've well understood but it seems that you need to link an action to a rule (when the document is created, you need to generate a control code). In an action you can do what you want (generating the code in the action, or call a webservice) => http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the "cm:countable" aspect. You do not have uniqueness guaranteed OOTB, so take that into account.

Example:
http://www.avantec.se/howto-create-an-auto-increment-field-on-an-object-in-alfresco/