# How does cm:countable aspect works in alfresco?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, aspect

I have added:

```
        <mandatory-aspects>
            <aspect>cm:countable</aspect>
        </mandatory-aspects>
```

To list definition, so every item should have "increment" field. But when list items are created nothig happened. I have check the follwoing code:

1. `nodeService.getAspects(nodeRef)` return all defined aspects for item, `cm:countable` presents in this list.
2. `nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, QName.createQName("http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0", "countable"))` return null.
3. `nodeService.getProperties(nodeRef)` returns all properties but no `countable` key is present.

I have search in alfresco sources and found `CounterIncrementActionExecuter` is extends `ActionExecuterAbstractBase` and defines `executeImpl`, but:

1. `executeImpl` is not invoked at new list item creation.
2. `ActionExecuterAbstractBase#isApplicableType` also not invoked.
3. `ActionExecuterAbstractBase#isApplicableType` "looks" at `applicableTypes` variable which is **not** populatd explicitly in `CounterIncrementActionExecuter`. So it is unclear how it should be populated and when.

So the question is - how does `cm:countable` aspect actually works in alfresco?

**UDPATE**

As I see counter is incremented in java code. So is safe to use it with one database and multuple alfresco instances connected to db?

Comment: See if this helps you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843229/auto-incrementing-unique-id-in-alfresco/

Comment: Source code looks like `CounterIncrementActionExecuter`. I think it is better to use build-in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This aspect is used generally by Alfresco administrator.It automatically increments the value of a number (integer) property when node is hit by services. This will generally only be used by Alfresco Administrators

**cm:countable** aspect has property called **cm:counter** which keeps track of current count.

So, your code for fetching property should be.

```
nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, QName.createQName("http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0", "counter"))
```

Now it works based on policy which is tied to that aspect. So, whenever node is invoked that counter is incremented.