# How to make the number field auto increment?

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I have a form in which I want to have number field and that should be auto increment. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Increment based on which previous value?

Comment: Yes Increment based on previous value.

Answer (score 2):

There's an aspect called `countable` aspect, and it does just that. However, it works with it's own property - `countable` - so if you're looking to use your own property - you will need to write some code.

http://avantec.se/2013/12/05/howto-create-an-auto-increment-field-on-an-object-in-alfresco/

[How does cm:countable aspect works in alfresco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076223/how-does-cmcountable-aspect-works-in-alfresco)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I asked about alfresco BPM. Aspects are related to ECM. How to make number field auto increment in BPM?

Answer (score 0):

Write a task listener. The task listener can be responsible for looking up the latest number, incrementing it, then setting the process or task variable with the new value.